# Why is the animation of the curve choppy?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

Sorry newbie here. When I move a ball along the path, the animation is choppy and I already tried to soften it and move the keyframes, but it's still the same result as shown in this video.

[image: See the ball]

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: Sorry, its done now

Comment: How does the animation of the ball work? Looks like you have made it a child of the BezierCurve.001. Why not use a *Follow Path* object constraint?